# Two listeners for same sensor event

Tags: android, accelerometer, android-sensors

I wanted to learn more about using sensors in Android. I made a small application for testing accelerometer. When it detects shake it displays *Toast* message. I put appropriate listener in a service.

I also have a flashlight application on my phone (downloaded from market). Flashlight can be started by shaking the phone. But when I installed my application and tried to shake the phone I always got just *Toast* message. Flashlight won't never start.

Is there a rule how Android should behave in a situation when there are two applications which should react on same sensor event?

EDIT

I made one more application. It is the same as the first one. Only my *Toast* message was different. When I try to shake my phone  I get both of *Toast* messages.

Comment: Let us see some code pliz. Be aware to put correctly the permissons

Comment: @alejandrocordon My code is working. I used a code I found in SO answers. I just want to know how android reacts when there are two listeners for same event. Which one has advantage?